# How to replace matching parentheses?

Tags: latex, replace, balanced-parentheses

I write (and rewrite) a lot of mathematical formulas in LaTeX with Emacs. I frequently run into situations where I want to change a pair of matching parentheses, to improve readability. My Emacs is kind enough to show me the matching delimiter, but how do I change it programmatically?

For example, change the outer delimiters in one go:

```
( (\sqrt{a} + b)^{-1} + c^{-1} )
```

to

```
[ (\sqrt{a} + b)^{-1} + c^{-1} ]
```

Comment: Note it would also be interesting if such code could change e.g. `\bigl(...\bigr)` to `\Bigl(...\Bigr)` etc.

Comment: Here I gave an example of a simplified LaTeX grammar using PEG: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36541/query-replace-regexp-alternative-capable-of-handling-nested-braces/36559#36559 this would be one way to approach this problem.

Comment: @wvxvw I looked at your approach when I wrote this question, and indeed it looks interesting! A also hope there is something, perhaps simpler, out there. Emacs is already aware of the matching delimiter since it is highlighted. Maybe this could be leveraged?

Comment: Related Stack Overflow thread: [How can you modify two matching delimiters at once with Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538688/how-can-you-modify-two-matching-delimiters-at-once-with-emacs)

Comment: Emacs knows to highlight the matching delimiter because either the mode implements `forward-sexp-function` (which, I'm guessing TeX mode does), or it will use `scan-sexps` to find the possible match. In the later case, the match will not always be correct. So, if all you need is to match matching delimiters, you can check the syntax of the character under point. If it's `$`, then it has to have a match, and you could use `forwad-sexp` to get to its match.

Comment: All requirements here are not fully specified. For an instance: What are outer delimiters? What happens if there is a deeper nesting level of parentheses? A clean specification is the first step to an implementation. Note that there is [cexp.el](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/cexp) for matching combinations of regexps and sexps that might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `smartparens` package. It includes a function called `sp-rewrap-sexp`, which is exactly what you need. The project homepage (https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens) has some gifs clearly showing the functionality.

Answer (score 11):

For those using evil you can use [evil-surround](https://github.com/emacs-evil/evil-surround) which gives you the `c s` motion (change, surround).

For your example then just do `c s ( [` (motion, from type of paren, to type of paren)

Comment: Just what I needed!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I use the code below and bind `yf/replace-or-delete-pair` to `M-D`.

Example usage : with point on `(`, I hit `M-D [` and the `()` pair becomes a `[]` pair. If you hit `M-D RET` instead, the pair will be removed.

This code uses the syntax table, which means that for some pairs you'll have to specify the closing paren yourself. e.g. in html-mode, `()` can be replaced by `<>` by hitting `M-D <`. However, in many modes `<>` isn't a recognized pair, and `M-D <` will say "Don't know how to close <". You can then you just type `>`.

```el
(defun yf/replace-or-delete-pair (open)
  "Replace pair at point by OPEN and its corresponding closing character.
The closing character is lookup in the syntax table or asked to
the user if not found."
  (interactive
   (list
    (read-char
     (format "Replacing pair %c%c by (or hit RET to delete pair):"
             (char-after)
             (save-excursion
               (forward-sexp 1)
               (char-before))))))
  (if (memq open '(?\n ?\r))
      (delete-pair)
    (let ((close (cdr (aref (syntax-table) open))))
      (when (not close)
        (setq close
              (read-char
               (format "Don't know how to close character %s (#%d) ; please provide a closing character: "
                       (single-key-description open 'no-angles)
                       open))))
      (yf/replace-pair open close))))

(defun yf/replace-pair (open close)
  "Replace pair at point by respective chars OPEN and CLOSE.
If CLOSE is nil, lookup the syntax table. If that fails, signal
an error."
  (let ((close (or close
                   (cdr-safe (aref (syntax-table) open))
                   (error "No matching closing char for character %s (#%d)"
                          (single-key-description open t)
                          open)))
        (parens-require-spaces))
    (insert-pair 1 open close))
  (delete-pair)
  (backward-char 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

`ar-parentized2bracketed-atpt` would do the task.

It comes along with `ar-braced2parentized-atpt` and basically all respective combinations.

Get it from thingatpt-transform-delimited.el of

URL: https://github.com/andreas-roehler/thing-at-point-utils

An abstracted class of commands transforms all delimited forms, for example:

```
ar-delimited2bracketed-atpt
```

These commandes are delivered in same repo by

thingatpt-transform-generic-delimited.el

Answer (score 0):

Matching parentheses are visualised with `show-paren-mode`. The logical approach is to base the function to change parens to the same underlying logic and function. When matching parens are highlighted, you can call the function `toggle-parens` defined below:

```
(defun toggle-parens ()
  "Toggle parens () <> [] at cursor.

Turn on `show-paren-mode' to see matching pairs of parentheses
and other characters in buffers. This function then uses the same
function `show-paren-data-function' to find and replace them with
the other pair of brackets.

This function can be easily modified and expanded to replace
other brackets. Currently, mismatch information is ignored and
mismatched parens are changed based on the left one."
  (interactive)
  (let* ((parens (funcall show-paren-data-function))
         (start (if (< (nth 0 parens) (nth 2 parens))
                    (nth 0 parens) (nth 2 parens)))
         (end (if (< (nth 0 parens) (nth 2 parens))
                  (nth 2 parens) (nth 0 parens)))
         (startchar (buffer-substring-no-properties start (1+ start)))
         (mismatch (nth 4 parens)))
    (when parens
      (pcase startchar
        ("(" (toggle-parens--replace "[]" start end))
        ("[" (toggle-parens--replace "()" start end))))))

(defun toggle-parens--replace (pair start end)
  "Replace parens with a new PAIR at START and END in current buffer.

A helper function for `toggle-parens'."
  (goto-char start)
  (delete-char 1)
  (insert (substring pair 0 1))
  (goto-char end)
  (delete-char 1)
  (insert (substring pair 1 2)))
```